# CakePHP Security Issue

Tags: security, cakephp

I have made a simple Blog site with CakePHP. Its working good in my localhost(WampServer), doesn't show any security issue here. But, when I uploaded the site in a real server, it shows : `getmypid() has been disabled for security reasons [CORE/Cake/Utility/String.php, line 88]` . What should I do now ? It looks ugly for a real website.

Comment: are you running your site with debug > 0 ? (unlike the error in the question that _is_ a security issue - don't do that).

Comment: what's that ? how to do that ? what should I do ? @AD7six

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake is using `getmypid()` for generating `uuids`.

I would recommend you contact the host to enable it, or enable in your php.ini if possible. If neither of these are possible you should start looking for another host which will provide you with a virtual server like Amazon AWS or Rackspace.